# Should we add DevExpress to our ASP.NET MVC standard toolset?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress-mvc

We use DevExpress but not on our web apps yet. I'm hesitant to add more technology to our ASP.NET MVC apps, but the DevExpress html widgets look pretty awesome.

At the moment we use MVC WebGrid - it works fine and we can get it to do *most* of what we need.

The DevExpress MVC GridView would be a huge upgrade in functionality - we don't need a lot of it, but users would really like some of the functionality we could add. And using the GridView would probably lead to using more web features of theirs.

We also use Bootstrap, among other things.

How problematic and/or often are DevExpress upgrades / patches for you?  Is this going to be a good thing or has it been a sore spot with developers having to maintain DevExpress in your web apps?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is opinion based but I am going to answer anyways. Devexpress Web Version doesn't have all the functionality of Desktop version. It is also not as flexible. Many limitations are because of nature of web itself. The problem we had when we employed Devexpress in our web apps was that, may time we would get some requirements, which devexpress couldn't handle. This meant we had to find hacky solutions to achieve what we wanted. We also had to wait for features to roll out and it would take quite a long time.

Upgrades itself has been flawless but it does lock you into Devexpress world. You have to do things their designated way. If all you want to use is GridView then it is fine as you are already familiar with Devexpress. Make sure that all the features that you want, or may want is available first.